# How to bring std::cout output back to the top after a new line

Tags: c++, winapi

I have the following menu, which is supposed to update based on whether the user has typed the keys <kbd>F1</kbd> or <kbd>F2</kbd>:

```
int main()
{
    bool f1 = false;
    bool f2 = false;
 
    while (true)    
    {
        std::cout << "[F1]:  " << (f1 ? "ON" : "OFF") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[F2]:  " << (f2 ? "ON" : "OFF") << std::endl;
        std::cout << "[INS] to quit" << std::endl;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_INSERT) & 0x1)
            break;

        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 0x1)
            f1 = !f1;
        
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F2) & 0x1)
            f2 = !f2;
        
        Sleep(100);
        cleanWindow();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Now, I was using `system("cls")` before and it was working "fine", but I've been told that I should rather use the Win32 API for cleaning out the console, and so I created `cleanWindow()` as described by [this MSVC article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/clearing-the-screen).

```
DWORD cleanWindow()
{
    HANDLE hStdOut;

    hStdOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    // Fetch existing console mode so we correctly add a flag and not turn off others
    DWORD mode = 0;
    if (!GetConsoleMode(hStdOut, &mode))
    {
        return ::GetLastError();
    }

    // Hold original mode to restore on exit to be cooperative with other command-line apps.
    const DWORD originalMode = mode;
    mode |= ENABLE_VIRTUAL_TERMINAL_PROCESSING;

    // Try to set the mode.
    if (!SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, mode))
    {
        return ::GetLastError();
    }

    // Write the sequence for clearing the display.
    // \x1b[2J is the code for clearing the screen and set cursor to home
    DWORD written = 0;
    PCWSTR sequence = L"\x1b[2J";
    if (!WriteConsoleW(hStdOut, sequence, (DWORD)wcslen(sequence), &written, NULL))
    {
        // If we fail, try to restore the mode on the way out.
        SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, originalMode);
        return ::GetLastError();
    }

    // To also clear the scroll back, emit L"\x1b[3J" as well.
    // 2J only clears the visible window and 3J only clears the scroll back.

    // Restore the mode on the way out to be nice to other command-line applications.
    SetConsoleMode(hStdOut, originalMode);
}
```

Now, the problem is that the "menu" is at the end of command prompt rather than at the start, as it was with `system("cls")`:

[image: output]

My question is, how do I do fix this? How do I bring the output back to the top of the shell?

**EDIT:**

I also edited the `cleanWindow()` function to write the sequences: `\033[2J` and `L"\033[H"` with [`WriteConsoleW()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/writeconsole), which works, but I still get the "blinking" effect just like with `system("cls")`, which is something I was trying to avoid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`SetConsoleCursorPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/setconsolecursorposition) to set the cursor location back to the top left after doing the clear.

There are also [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) (similar to the one you use to clear the screen) that would allow you to reposition the cursor.

```
"\033[r;cH"
```

replacing `r` with the row and `c` the column to move to. They are 1-based, and default to the top left, so you can use `"\033[1;1H"` or just `"\033[H"`